# How to create a proxy to access sip which is IP locked

Tags: windows, proxy, sip

Here is what i want to do , I have a sip phone configured on my home system which only works on my static IP , Using zoiper soft phone. I want to be able to connect to my system remotely and be able to use my IP phone remotely . Can you please tell me how I can go about doing that.. ?

From the research I did I think I need to configure a proxy on my home system to which I should connect which will give my laptop the same IP address as my home system.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need a proxy, first, it would be necessary more information about the topology of your home network.

I will consider you have the common, a cable modem, or a router that lets you go to internet.

first you need to know what ports your sip system are using, and then you need to forward that ports on your cable modem o router to the local ip of your sip home server.

when you configure zoiper from an external device you will point the ip server account to your public ip assigned to your router, and if you configured ok the forwarding, it will forward the necessary ports to you sip server.